# How to add "other" option to mat-select in Angular 5 / Material 2

Tags: angular

I have a mat-select drop-down menu in angular 5. I would like to have an "other" option that, if selected, displays a text field with a manual input. How can I achieve this?
My idea was to address another ngModel Boolean field, which then allows a *ng-if to display the text field, but even if it would work (I don't know how) it doesn't seem very elegant....

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="regime" name="regime-input">
        <mat-option [value]=1>daily</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=7>weekly</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=30>monthly</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=0>bei Bedarf</mat-option>
        <mat-option >other</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Your idea is the way to do it. I suggest you try it out and update the question if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple reference to show an input conditionally:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <!-- Notice the "#regimeWidget"! -->
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="regime" name="regime-input" #regimeWidget>
        <mat-option [value]=1>daily</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=7>weekly</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=30>monthly</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=0>bei Bedarf</mat-option>
        <mat-option >other</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<ng-container *ngIf="!regimeWidget.value">
    <!-- Add your input here -->
    <span>You selected "Other"</span>
</ng-container>
```

This relies on the "other" option having an undefined (or null) `value`.

Comment: Thank you for the great solution. The only problem is that "other" is not shown as selected is there also such an elegant solution for that?

Comment: @KrombopulosMichael Seems that mat-select just behaves that way. You can add a placeholder to the dropdown, though. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwbetq?file=app/select-value-binding-example.html

Comment: This behavior is explained [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwbetq?file=app/select-value-binding-example.html).

Comment: I made a small change on the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwbetq-dcoqhs?embed=1&file=app/select-value-binding-example.html) The "None" stays as selected

Comment: Placeholder solution doesn't work if you have <mat-label> and want to show both. E.g. "Your favorite animal" as label and "--Please select--" as a value for unselected case.